We've reached 500 questions (18/19th September 2012)
I just thought I'd share the milestone of reaching 500 questions.


Yay! How will we celebrate this? Perhaps Mien could make some waffles?

Not sure what the proper answer to this question is, so I'll just say...
Congratulations CogSci!

Keep up the great work!

